# Narrow buffer, using org-match-sparse-tree?

Tags: emacs, tags, elisp, org-mode

I would like to filter the buffer in Org-mode to only those headings that match certain tags.

I tried `C-c /` followed by `tag1&tag2`. But instead of narrowing the buffer, Emacs just highlights the asterisk next to each heading that has those tags...

How can I change this so that Emacs actually narrows the buffer to those matched headlines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The search regexp used by the original poster is probably incorrect. The sub-function used by `org-occur` to set the boundaries for the highlighted result is rather simple -- `(while (re-search-forward regexp nil t) . . .)` The beginning and ending of the matched pattern determine the boundaries of the highlighted area -- i.e., `(match-beginning 0)`, and `(match-end 0)`.

To search for headlines containing *either* or *both* tags, the regexp `:tag1:\|:tag2:` is used when `org-occur` is called interactively -- i.e., **just one backslash and pipe**.  When `org-occur` is used NON-interactively, **two (2) backslashes and a pipe** are required -- e.g., `(org-occur ":tag1:\\|:tag2:")`

When looking for two tags that are *together* in a specific order, the regexp looks like this:  `:tag1:tag2:`

The default behavior of `org-occur` is to fold everything and then unfold only matched results -- with an exception for previously matched results remaining visible, *unless* the argument `keep-previous` is non-nil.  If the buffer looks completely unfolded (after a search using `org-occur`), then the regexp that was used probably matched **everything**.

It is also prudent to check and verify that a current version of `org-mode` is being used -- `M-x org-version RET`.

---

Example of a search using `org-occur` for the tag `:lasc:`

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/org_occur.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks. The regex isn't really this issue. What I would like to do is completely hide any headers that do not matching my search criteria (the same way we are able to narrow a buffer to a specific subtree).

Comment: You may be interested in taking a look at the interactive functions for `org-tags-view` and `org-search-view` -- both generate a buffer containing only the results of the query, without the need to fold or hide anything.  `org-occur` does not have a provision to completely hide everything except the search result (but it hides almost everything) -- that would be a custom feature for future implementation.

Comment: I posted an example of what `org-occur` should look like, just in case you are seeing something different.  It hides almost everything except the main heading.

Answer (score 2):

Doing `C-c / m tag1&tag2` does what you want -- except for level 1 headings (those are always visible, even if they don't contain useful entries; but level 2+ entries are only visible if they match your request).

That works the same way as `C-c / t` for example (all TODO in the current buffer).

Comment: Ah, good observation! I wonder though, if this can be customized to apply to top-level headlines as well? Seems strange that they should be excluded...? Thanks!!

Comment: AFAICT, that would require a change in Org code base. In the meanwhile, if you're really annoyed by the current behavior, a workaround can be to wrap your level 1 headings in a "meta-level 1" heading... That way, your current level 1 become level 2 sections, and will be hidden ;-)

Comment: I think  [org-ql-sparse-tree](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql/blob/master/README.org#org-ql-sparse-tree-query-key-keep-previous-buffer-current-buffer) from the awesome org-ql package can do what you want. The normal org sparse tree itself always shows level one headings as org-overview is called in the beginning. My [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52117/19819) shows a possible workaround, just leave the unhide parent part away to do what you want.